# Rename column in derived class using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have asked question in a different post, but seems that was not the right question, so going to reword here:

I have three classes:

```
public class StateLog : BaseModel
{
    public Guid StateLogId { get; set; }
    public Guid LookupMasterId { get; set; }


    public  Guid EntityId { get; set; }

    public string Discriminator { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual LookupMaster State { get; set; }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class ApplicationState : StateLog
{
   [Column("EntityId")]
   public  Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

There is another Class DocumentStates which inherits from StateLog.

Application:

```
public class Application : BaseModel
{
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }        
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ApplicationTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool? AuthorizedToWork { get; set; } = false;
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationTitle { get; set; }
    public string WorkStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> SignedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool? Signed { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationSelfDeclaration> ApplicationSelfDeclarations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationState> ApplicationStates { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateLog> StateLogs { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to save statelogs for both application and documents in same table and based on Discriminator, fetch data.

E.g.

```
_context.Applications.include(a => a.ApplicationState)
```

This is not not working. ApplicationState should Alias EntityId column as ApplicationId. But it is not working.

Any idea what my options are at this point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share Application class.So Are Application and ApplicationState entity objects?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: _context.Applications.Include("ApplicationStates").Include("StateLogs") try this.